# How to give combinations of letters and numbers using FakerLibrary in robot framework

Tags: python

How to give combination of letters and numbers using FakerLibrary in robot framework.

Example: Shop generating coupon code like WORLD123, WO1RL2D3....

fake.name()

fake.address()

fake.email()

fake.text()

fake.country()

fake. ?????         <-- Which one i want to using for COUPON CODE

Comment: show your code trials and errors

Comment: Isn't that Python's FakerLibrary, not RF's FakerLibrary? Hence, you could add python tag here...

Answer (score 2):

As a solution try `fake.password()`: https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/providers/faker.providers.misc.html

Example:

```
for i in range(5):
    print(fake.password(length=8, special_chars=False, digits=True, upper_case=True, lower_case=False))

>> 5NBY2KAR
>> 8874FMWL
>> GFT682JL
>> K8AW00CU
>> U0DTVJQE
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather go without `FakerLibrary` because `String` library already has the functionality and it is a built-in library, meaning less dependencies.

You can change `[UPPER]` to `[LETTERS]` if letters don't have to be uppercase.

Example:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    String

*** Test Cases ***
Random Coupon String
    ${random_coupon_string}=     Generate Random String    length=8    chars=[UPPER][NUMBERS]
    Log To Console    ${random_coupon_string}
```

Example outputs:

```
T5F3JQZO
1LTTYXQA
D6AW465K
```

String library Generate Random String docs [here](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Generate%20Random%20String).